# Graddle-wrapper distributionUrl doesn't change

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, wrapper

I use a graddle-wrapper in my project. I fixed the distributionURL manually:

`distributionUrl=https://privateRepo/gradle-2.10-bin.zip`

I tried to change the variable manually (`distributionUrl=https://privateRepo/gradle-5.0-bin.zip`) but it keeps creating the first distributionURL after I run cordova build android.

I don't get why it's still the first property.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can get over these types of problems by doing a clean build 
in Android Studio:
Build>Clean Project
Hope It Helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm using cordova. I think cordova clean does the same thing.

Comment: Oh Ok. You're Most Welcome (did it do the job tho?)